# Flutter Web - Image Painted with Color Filter to Become Invisible No Longer Works After Upgrading Flutter to 3.7.1

Tags: flutter

Have raw image pngs which are all white in colour which, upon loading in a Flutter app, are each painted with specific `Paint`s to form composites of various different colours.

One of the `Paint`s acts as an invisible paint so that we can have specific images in the composites to show/not show according to runtime conditions.

This trick works fine when **Flutter version 3.3.9** is used but now, we have upgraded to **Flutter version 3.7.1** and the invisible `Paint` trick in our composites no longer works.

To be specific, it no longer works when run on Chrome Web browser (i.e. flutter web). The invisible `Paint` trick still works as expected in Flutter native mobile app.

Invisible Paint we define as follows:

```
// Invisible Paint
static final Paint invisiblePaint = Paint()
    ..colorFilter = const ColorFilter.mode(Color(0x00000000), BlendMode.modulate);
```

When we paint the images to become invisible we paint them on `Canvas` as follows:

```
canvas.drawImage(image, Offset.zero, invisiblePaint);
```

When run using **Flutter 3.7.1** on Chrome Web Browser the image remains white as in the raw image png as though the invisible paint is being laid on top of the raw image's white pixels instead of replacing the pixel colours altogether.

Any ideas why this no longer works in Flutter stable version `3.7.1`?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make the raw images invisible when run in Chrome web browser using Flutter stable `3.7.1` by redefining the invisible `Paint` just to use a `Color` instead of a `ColorFilter` as follows:

```
// Invisible Paint
static final Paint invisiblePaint = Paint()..color = const Color(0x00000000));
```

With invisible `Paint` defined like this the code behaves as expected in both Chrome web browser app as well as native mobile app.

It should be noted however that in cases where the raw white images need to be painted an actual colour then the `Paint`s still need to use `ColorFilter`s.

I don't know enough about the ins and outs of Flutter `ui.Image` renderings using `Paint` `Color`s/`ColorFilter`s to explain why it works one way but not the other or why the problem was only being seen in flutter web but not flutter native mobile app.